# Ping reboot script percentage packet loss

Tags: linux, bash, busybox

need script for reboot modem when packet loss > 70
i see it:

```
    a="$(ping -c10 "host" | awk 'END{print}' | awk '{ print $7 }' | sed s/%//g)"; 
b=70;
if [ "$a" -gt "$b" ]; then
        echo "trouble ping" #reboot modem
else
        echo "ping ok"
fi
```

When the host does not answer first str = 100 (without "%") its correct, but when he answers the output is empty (why not 0), i can't understand the reason

Comment: please update the question to show the complete output from `ping -c10 "host"` for both scenarios: 'host answers' and 'host does not answer'

Comment: the reason I ask for this additional info ... on my system when 'host answers' the last line of `ping -c10` output looks like `round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 232.499/246.559/252.197/6.052 ms` which has just 5 space-delimited fields so `awk {print $7}` is going to print nothing ... which may be the reason your code sets `a` to `empty`, but to know for sure we need to see what the `ping` output looks like on your system

Comment: @markp-fuso hi
--- 10.119.101.240 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 19.260/27.710/41.860 ms
then ping unresponsive:
--- 172.16.74.13 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss

Comment: please cut-n-paste these into the question since actual formatting is of key importance in this case (and formatting is hard to read in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ping` output on my system when there's `0% packet loss` and `100% packet loss`:

```
$ ping -c10 yahoo.com
PING yahoo.com (98.137.11.164): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 98.137.11.164: icmp_seq=0 ttl=53 time=75.890 ms
... snip ...
64 bytes from 98.137.11.164: icmp_seq=9 ttl=53 time=75.553 ms
--- yahoo.com ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 73.983/76.589/78.678/1.682 ms

$ ping -c10 yahoo.com
PING yahoo.com (74.6.143.25): 56 data bytes
--- yahoo.com ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

It may make more sense to search for the string `packet loss` and then take the 7th (white space delimited) field, eg:

```
ping -c10 "host" | awk '/packet loss/{print int($7+0)}'
```

When applied to the 2x scenarios above this generates `0` and `100`, respectively.

**NOTES:**

- in the `awk` code the `$7+0` has the effect of stripping off trailing non-numeric characters (eg, `%`)
- in the `awk` code the `int()` insures we only generate an integer (in case `ping` were to ever generate a float/real value); `bash` only works with integers so we need to make sure we only pass an integer back to the calling process
- OP may want additional logic to handle a `ping` command that goes walkabout, eg, generates an error (`ping: unknown host`), generates nothing, hangs, etc

Answer (score -1):

came up on the other side

```
a="$(ping -c10 "host" | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print $1 }')"; 
b=7;
if [ "$b" -gt "$a" ]; then
        echo "trouble ping"
else
        echo "ping ok"
fi
```

anyway its work as i need